# Website freezing but only for certain users - unsure where to start

Tags: vue.js, debugging, vuex, freeze

I'm trying to build a Vue web app and a friend was using it when it froze. Refreshing the page or opening a new tab and going to the page didn't fix it, and it would just keep loading until chrome said the page was unresponsive.

I thought it might be a network issue on their side but it works fine on their phone. Then I thought maybe there was a localStorage or cookie corruption issue, but then it was still broken on a different browser(chrome & edge).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTLTs.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbjdr.png

This site doesn't seem to show any HTML and upon reload, nothing pops up in the network tab.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjqrk.png

The site uses vue3, vuex, fullcalendar, fontawesome, lzutf8(compression algorithm package). It's hosted on netlify.

Honestly, I don't even know where to start debugging this since I can't reproduce the issue on my computer and it makes it worse than I don't physically have the laptop in front of me. Here are some issues I think it may be:

- There is some corrupt data between chrome and edge that's causing the site to freeze
- I'm using a compression algorithm package to compress the vue store into a copy/pastable string. It's possible this is causing the site to slow when vuex tries to load the getter for the compressed store, but if the localstorage is empty all it has to compress is empty arrays so I don't see how compression would cause an issue.
- A firewall on the device could be blocking the website
- Maybe there's a chance Netlify could be blocking the site?
- Potentially there's some issue with vue or vuex that I don't know about?

Here's the github repo: https://github.com/ZombiMigz/cpp-scheduler-webapp
and the website is deployed here: https://cppscheduler.com/

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First of all, there's no screen with "page unresponsive". Was the error there both with devtools open and closed? You won't go far without a repro. It's safe to assume that this could be network problem, either temporary or specific to user's location. It means something that both browsers behaved this way, but they could become poisoned at some point. It's unclear Try to ask to open in incognito, and with some VPN extension, and ping the domain to make sure which IP it is. "Netlify could be blocking the site?" - more like someone is blocking Netlify, could easily happen with a cloud.

Comment: That it wasn't reproducible on a phone suggests that it could be a network if these were different ISP and DNS. It would be useful to know which phone and browser though. If it's Android Chrome, chances are that it should behave very similarly to a desktop.